# Splitting and select string starting with uppercase letter with Regex

Tags: regex, string, split, uppercase

I have a string like below:

`"This Is A TestSentence For The Purpose of Asking a Question"`

I would like to retrieve everything starting from "Sentence" with Regex, that means:

`"Sentence For The Purpose of Asking a Question"`

I have tried this, but it also includes the lowercase letter preceding Sentence:

```
\w[A-Z].*
```

The text is not specific which means the Regex pattern should match any sentence with this structure, not the specific text (There is only one instance with connected upper and lowercase words)

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Appreciate any help from the experts here!

Answer (score 0):

you shoul read about "regex lookaround"

this should be the regex you are looking for

```
(?<=\w)[A-Z].*
```